# How can I update a status for test case in ALM using REST API

Tags: java, rest, alm

I have been tried to connect the ALM by using REST API, and successfully made the connection in ALM. But, I'm not sure how can I modify the entities(Test, TestLab, Requirements) status. I'm using JAVA as my programming language.

Example:

I have a test set which contains multiple test steps. I have to update the status as PASSED by using REST API.

Is anybody have a solution on this? please share some code snippet or ideas.

Comment: Could you post your code for how you connected to ALM?  I'm really struggling to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP ALM help file has all the information you need to get started.

Afte you login to HP ALM (Thin Client), GoTO HELP -> API Reference -> RESTFUl API.

Not sure which scripting language you are using however your requirement could be achieved easily using simple CURL, Java, Python etc...

This would help someone who is new to HP REST API.

1. To find available HP API end-points,

`GET <QCSERVER>/qcbin/rest/resouce-list`